# 否定形の読みやすさについて

Tags: python, python3

リーダブルコードなどを読んで、否定はなるべく使わない方が良いというのは分かるのですが、
どうしても使わざるを得ない状況もあるかと思います。
その場合、例えばPythonでは以下どちらの書き方が良いのでしょうか？

```
if not hasSomething()
if doesNotHaveSomething()
```

もしくは他の書き方があれば教えてください

Answer (score 3):

リーダブルコードの主張はこうです

- 名前に否定形は使わない
- 条件式に否定は使わない

後者については、否定を使った方が読みやすい場合もあるとも書かれています。

> if not hasSomething()
>   if doesNotHaveSomething()

リーダブルコードではthenとelseをひっくり返して前者の`not`を消すことを考えろといっているわけですが、それが出来ないのであれば、前者を使うほうがよいでしょう。

後者は、`doesNotHaveSomething()`が`false`を返したときに結局どういう状態なのか考えるのが大変です。これが「名前に否定形を使わない」とされる理由です。

Comment: pythonってunlessないのか、初めて知った

Answer (score 1):

「(否定を)どうしても使わざるを得ない」=「否定を使うことがリーダブル」と読めますが。

Answer (score 0):

一般に「否定を使わない」というのは否定演算子を使うなという事ではなく、メソッド名などにおいての話なのではないでしょうか。
否定形の要素があるとそれの否定で「否定の否定」が出てきてしまう事、一貫性が失われる事、などが原因ではないでしょうか。
まさに、`doesNotHaveSomething()` などというメソッドを用意する必要はなくて、 `not hasSomething()` でいいよね？ という話だと思います。

（これに従うかどうかは主観の問題ですね）